# What does this symbol (reversed 1?) mean?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, logic

Could someone please elaborate what the name of this symbol is and how it is defined?

Thanks

> if $\sigma =\tau\upharpoonright [n]$ for

What I think it means in this context is that given an initial segment $\sigma$ of a finite, well-ordered set $\tau$, we can depict that initial segment $\sigma$ by taking $\tau$ and removing the last $n$ sequential elements in $\tau$.

Thanks

Comment: [Restriction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol $\upharpoonright$ is called "up harpoon barb right" or "up harpoon right".  Usually, it is used to denote [restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) to a smaller part (segment, domain, etc.).

For example, the following statement (*[Modern Mathematical Logic](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108973106)* by Joseph Mileti, p. 10) tells us that the sequence $\sigma$ consists of the initial $n$ elements of the sequence $\tau$, i.e., restricted to the first $n$-element part of $\tau$.

[image]